# in C, having an issue with finding the proper operators used to fix this code [SIMPLE] THE PROBLEM IS WITH (!=)

Tags: c

```
int main(){

  char password[10];
  int i = 0;
  printf("Please enter your password\n");
  scanf("%s", password);

  while (password != "juniorkid"){

  printf("Error\n");

  printf("Please enter your password\n");
  scanf("%s", password);

  i++;

  if (i>1){
    printf("Exceeded tries");
    break;

  }
else{
  printf("yay\n");
}

  }


}
```

 clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:20:19: warning: result of comparison against a
      string literal is unspecified (use strncmp
      instead) [-Wstring-compare]
  while (password != "juniorkid"){
                  ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
 ./main

Comment: You can not compare strings with a mathematical operator in C. It would end up comparing the addresses, since strings are just a pointer to an address. You need to use strcmp function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings)

Comment: @Nina *`since strings are just a pointer to an address`* No. They are not. C strings are **char arrays** but not pointers.

Comment: Are you impling char arrays are not Pointers?..... And does comparing c strings with a mathematical opator not compare their address? Nitpicking at every small thing isn't benefiting anyone.. Besides you basically repeated the same thing Isaid but as an answer instead of a comment even though the question had already been answered before which I posted a link to...BIG YIKES my dude

Answer (score 1):

`password != "juniorkid"` it does not compare the char arrays (C strings). It only compares the addresses of the char arrays and (which is obvious as they do not occupy the same memory)

you need to use string comparison function `strcmp`

Comment: You *can* do it, it just won't do what you might expect.